# how to close App1 after opening App2?

Tags: ios, swift, x-callback-url

I have two apps - `App1` and `App2`, and they communicate using `x-callback-url` protocol. My question is - how to close 'sender' `App1` after calling `App2`?

I don't need kill  `App1` when it's go background, only kill from specific function/viewcontroller in 0-2 seconds after redirection

p.s. after redirecting this code not executing at all.

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillDisappear(false)
         print("viewWillDisappear")
     }
```

some variation with calling closing before/after redirect gives nothing too

p.p.s. using this code to close app

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                        UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend))
                         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                          exit(0)
                         }
}
```

Comment: same developer account ?

Comment: yes, I'm the developer